# Use Endnotes in an rmarkdown Word Document

Tags: r, ms-word, r-markdown

Is it possible to set up an rmarkdown document so that when it renders a word document the footnotes show up as endnotes in the .docx file?

Comment: I think `pandoc` (and therefore `knitr` and Rmarkdown) does not support end-notes, but [it's not hard to do it yourself](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Convert-footnotes-to-endnotes-ccfd96a0-e26a-4edc-b5ec-7e1a1acd739e). (I realize this doesn't help you automate it, but I'm guessing an enterprising user could device a VBA or VBS macro to do it programmatically instead of through the Word interface.)

Answer (score -1):

yes it is easy. I guess at the moment you are doing this

```
Word^[footnote] another word
```

But if you do this

```
Word[^1] another word

... rest of document ...

[^1]: footnote
```

Then the footnotes appear at the end in docx and pdf.

Comment: The latter footnote format doesn't produce endnotes in Word, just footnotes.

Comment: Yeah, this is not on track......  this works in HTML and not in Word, which is really where the question comes from.  In Word we get the footnote on the same page, rather than at the end.  In HTML the whole thing is treated as one page, I guess :)